# Measure web application deployment time in glassfish

Tags: web-applications, deployment, glassfish-3

I would like to get some ideas on how to effectively measure an web application deployment time on a glassfish application server (version 3.1)?

One way I could think off was to turn on glassfish loggers which could log statements before and after the web application is deployed but I could not figure out which loggers to turn on.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GlassFish reports the deployment time already. Please check our server.log.

If I deloy an EAR GlassFish issues the following log statement after finishing the deployment:

```
    [#|2012-04-29T12:23:32.575+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-6;|XXXXX was successfully deployed in 26.307 milliseconds.|#]
```

Comment: The weird part is that I have this logger "javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin" at INFO log level but I do not have this message logged in the server.log. I deploy the application through the glassfish admin console (GUI). Any clue on what could be going wrong?